# Convert JSON to CSV with php (not a script)

Tags: php, json, csv

Each of my users has a JSON encoded string saved to a field called 'json'. There will be multiple multidimensional items but `nutrients` will not always be an element. This is the format:

```
$arr = array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'amount' => 5,
            'time' => '2:00 am',
            'nutrients' => array(
                'Macro' => array(
                    'water' => 0,
                    'carbs' => 0,
                ),
                'Micro' => array(
                    'zinc' => 0,
                )
            )
        );

$user->json = json_encode($arr);
$user->save();
```

I want to (in another view) convert `$user->json` into a CSV file. This is the closest I could get with code I found online but I still get an error ('fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given'):

```
$user = Auth::user();

$json_obj = json_decode ($user->json);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($json_obj as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

If I use `$json_obj = json_decode ($user->json, true);` I get the error "Array to string conversion"

Any help is appreciated, let me know if more information is needed. Thank you!

Comment: `$json_obj = json_decode($user->json, true)` (true means decode as associative array, not an object)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I tried that too but I get the error `Array to string conversion` (it doesn't tell me exactly which array/string).

Answer (score 0):

Well you got arrays in your array... thats why you get the error when you're doing the `json_decode($data, true)`. You got to decide how you want to format your other data like "nutrients".
I hope you get the point. The problem is that it expects an array of primitive data and not an array with another array in it.

Comment: I completely understand that I have a multidimensional array, it was stated in my second sentence. Reformatting my array isn't really an option, and I don't think it's an acceptable answer. I know it's not impossible to convert the JSON I have to CSV, is it just impossible in php? Do I need to out source the problem somehow? I think this would have worked better as a comment because it doesn't help me in the slightest.